# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'liblibc.a'

Tags: python-3.x, scapy

```
import scapy.all as scapy
def scan(ip):
    scapy.arping(ip)
scan("192.168.196.0")
```

Above error when using scapy for arping
python version 3.9.1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python scapy.all file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65410697/python-scapy-all-file-not-found)

Answer (score 24):

```
cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
ln -s -f libc.a liblibc.a
```

This creates a symbolic link to accommodate for the renamed file in python 3.9.

Comment: Thank you. It worked for me. In Manjaro 20.2, but `libc.a` file found in `/usr/lib/`

Comment: updating scapy to the dev version fixes it and is cleaner

Comment: In Fedora: `sudo ln -s -f /usr/lib64/libc.a /usr/lib64/liblibc.a`

Comment: On Arch using Python 3.9.3, upgrading to Scapy 2.4.5 from 2.4.4 fixed the issue

Comment: On Manjaro 21.2rc: `sudo ln -s -f /usr/lib64/libc.a /usr/lib64/liblibc.a`