# python scapy.all file not found

Tags: python, scapy, kali-linux

I have tried to run my program, and I have tried import `scapy` then import `scapy.all` but is will give me the same error. I am using kali-linux if that helps. The code that is causing the error is just from `scapy.all import *`

This is the full error output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bradz/test.py", line 24, in <module>
    from scapy.all import send, IP, TCP, ARP
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/scapy/all.py", line 16, in <module>
    from scapy.arch import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/scapy/arch/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from scapy.arch.bpf.core import get_if_raw_addr<br/>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/scapy/arch/bpf/core.py", line 30, in <module>
    LIBC = cdll.LoadLibrary(find_library("libc"))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ctypes/util.py", line 341, in find_library
    _get_soname(_findLib_gcc(name)) or _get_soname(_findLib_ld(name))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ctypes/util.py", line 147, in _findLib_gcc
    if not _is_elf(file):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ctypes/util.py", line 99, in _is_elf
    with open(filename, 'br') as thefile:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'liblibc.a'
```

Fixed it. You need to go to:

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scapy/arch/bpf/core.py
```

and edit the line

```
LIBC = cdll.LoadLibrary(find_library("libc"))
```

to

```
LIBC = cdll.LoadLibrary(find_library("c"))
```

Comment: [Another victim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65410481/filenotfounderror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-bliblibc-a).

Comment: tryed to roll back to an older version and it still has the same issue but as well it works fine in python2 not python3

Comment: With the same version of CPython, a rollback won't work. You'd need to either roll back your Python version, or update Scapy (the preferred way).

Comment: Fyi, you could post your workaround as an answer. It would be far more appropriate there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to have been a bug in the library that was [fixed 11 days ago](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/commit/46fa40fde4049ad7770481f8806c59640df24059):

> There is a regression in Python 3.9 with the `find_library()`
> function:
>
> ```
> >>> import ctypes.util
> >>> ctypes.util.find_library("libc")
>  Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>    File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ctypes/util.py", line 341, in find_library
>      _get_soname(_findLib_gcc(name)) or _get_soname(_findLib_ld(name))
>    File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ctypes/util.py", line 147, in _findLib_gcc
>      if not _is_elf(file):
>    File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ctypes/util.py", line 99, in _is_elf
>      with open(filename, 'br') as thefile:
>  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'liblibc.a'
> ```
>
> A workaround is to use `find_library("c")` instead. It also works in
> older versions of Python and that's already what's used in
> `contrib/isotp.py`.

Update scapy since you appear to be using a version of scapy that is incompatible with your version of CPython.

---

Actually, it looks like PyPI hasn't been updated yet, so you won't be able to update through `pip`. You may need to rollback your Python version until it's updated, or [manually install the patched scapy version from Github](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#current-development-version).