# Scapy can't install

Tags: python-3.x, scapy

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/predata/soft/Memcrashed-DDoS-Exploit/Memcrashed.py", line 5, in <module>
from scapy.all import *
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/scapy/all.py", line 18, in <module>
from scapy.arch import *
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/scapy/arch/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
from scapy.arch.bpf.core import get_if_raw_addr
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/scapy/arch/bpf/core.py", line 29, in <module>
LIBC = cdll.LoadLibrary(find_library("libc"))
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ctypes/util.py", line 341, in find_library
_get_soname(_findLib_gcc(name)) or _get_soname(_findLib_ld(name))
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ctypes/util.py", line 147, in _findLib_gcc
if not _is_elf(file):
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ctypes/util.py", line 99, in _is_elf
with open(filename, 'br') as thefile:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'liblibc.a'
```

i can't run scapy file or something like this, can someone help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python scapy.all file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65410697/python-scapy-all-file-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

You should retry using the Github version of Scapy. This was fixed

See https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#current-development-version