# Not able to download scapy-python3-0.26 in kali linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, scapy, kali-linux

I have installed scapy-python3-0.26 tar.gz file from here---> https://pypi.org/project/scapy-python3/#files
then i did **cd /Downloads/scapy-python3-0.26** 
 then i allowed all permissions to the file by **chmod +x subfile name**

then i wrote **python3 setup.py install**  but i didnt got installed  but showed this code 
root@-kali-linux:~/Downloads/scapy-python3-0.26# python3 setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
package init file 'scapy/**init**.py' not found (or not a regular file)
package init file 'scapy/**init**.py' not found (or not a regular file)
running install_lib
running install_egg_info
Removing /usr/local/lib/**python3.9**/dist-packages/scapy_python3-0.26.egg-info
Writing /usr/local/lib/**python3.9**/dist-packages/scapy_python3-0.26.egg-info

**I even tried it with python instead of python3 but got the same results** 
root@-kali-linux:~/Downloads/scapy-python3-0.26# python3 setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
package init file 'scapy/**init**.py' not found (or not a regular file)
package init file 'scapy/**init**.py' not found (or not a regular file)
running install_lib
running install_egg_info
Removing /usr/local/lib/**python2.7**/dist-packages/scapy_python3-0.26.egg-info
Writing /usr/local/lib/**python2.7**/dist-packages/scapy_python3-0.26.egg-info 
instead of **Finished processing dependencies for scapy-python3-0.26**
PLEASE HELP IN INSTALLING THIS  I NEED IT FOR A TOOL CALLED UFONET

Comment: Just use `scapy`. `scapy-python3` is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem

Open terminal and type

cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

( however some may have only /usr/lib/ , so please mind that )

And then type

ln -s -f libc.a liblibc.a

And then you'll be able to finish installing scapy

Reference:-
[FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'liblibc.a'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65410481/filenotfounderror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-bliblibc-a)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `pip`?

```
pip install --pre scapy[complete]
```

If `scapy` is only needed for one project, then you'd better have a look at `virtualenv`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30072728)