# Scapy module not working on RPI with error: "No such file or directory: b'liblibc.a'"

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

when I run anyu python using scapy fully updated it does this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/pentest/NetScan/netscan.py", line 36, in <module>
    from scapy.all import *
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scapy/all.py", line 16, in <module>
    from scapy.arch import *
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scapy/arch/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from scapy.arch.bpf.core import get_if_raw_addr
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scapy/arch/bpf/core.py", line 29, in <module>
    LIBC = cdll.LoadLibrary(find_library("libc"))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ctypes/util.py", line 341, in find_library
    _get_soname(_findLib_gcc(name)) or _get_soname(_findLib_ld(name))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ctypes/util.py", line 147, in _findLib_gcc
    if not _is_elf(file):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ctypes/util.py", line 99, in _is_elf
    with open(filename, 'br') as thefile:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'liblibc.a'
```

I tired to fix by doing based on this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65410481/filenotfounderror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-bliblibc-a)

```
cd /usr/lib
sudo ln -s -f libc.a liblibc.a
```

but it dons't work.
How can I fix this problem

Comment: did you update using pip?

Comment: I updated scapy and know it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fore me when I updated scapy it works.

Comment: did you update using pip?